# CakePHP Validation nonBlank fails Whether the Field is Empty or !Empty

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

The docs say that `'notBlank'` is a validation rule for fields that you want to make sure they are not empty, as in `!empty($somevalue)`, but when I leave the field blank ('') or when I put a value in the field `('s0meCraZyPasSworD')` it still display the error message?

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?  The rest of the validations work like minlength, but I commented them out to get a better idea of why `'notBlank'` doesn't appear to be working...

```
CONTROLLER:
// Set of validation rules to be run
$validateRules = [
    'fieldList' => [
        'currentpassword',
        'newpassword',
        'confirmpassword'
    ]
];

if ($this->Admin->validates( $validateRules )) {
    ...
}

MODEL:
class Admin extends AppModel
{
    public $name = 'Admin';

    public $validate = [
        'currentpassword' => [
            'notBlank'  => [
                'rule'    => 'notBlank',
                'message' => 'Current password is required.'
            ]
        ],
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tagged CakePHP 2.4 - `notBlank` was [added in 2.7](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#Validation::notBlank) so you have to use [notEmpty](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#Validation::notEmpty) or set [allowEmpty to false](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#allowempty)...

Answer (score 0):

> The data sent to the model’s save() method must contain data for the
>   login field. If it doesn’t, validation will fail. The default value
>   for this key is boolean false.
>
> `required => true` does not mean the same as the validation rule
>   notBlank(). `required => true` **indicates that the array key must be**
>   **present** - it does not mean it must have a value

From the official website:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#required

So you will need another rule like the [allowEmpty](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#allowempty) to validate this field and not the `notBlank` rule.